# How can I use a parameter more than once in Mybatis

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis

I want to use some parameter for more than once, the method in interface like this:

```java
List<PoliceCompanyJointCheck> selectJointCheckPageRedList(@Param("pageModel") PageModel<PoliceCompanyJointCheck> pageModel,
                                                              @Param("query") PoliceCompanyJointCheckQuery query,
                                                              @Param("companyId") String companyId,
                                                              @Param("checkRecordType") Integer checkRecordType);
```

And the SQL in xml file are as follows:

```xml
<select id="selectJointCheckPageRedList" resultType="com.jiumai.base.pm.entity.PoliceCompanyJointCheck">
        SELECT joint_check_table.check_id AS checkId, joint_check_table.check_date AS checkDate,
               joint_check_table.check_record_type AS checkRecordType, joint_check_table.company_id AS companyId,
               joint_check_table.company_name AS companyName,
               joint_check_table.rest_score AS restScore,
               pafen_table.total_pafen AS totalPafen,
               (joint_check_table.rest_score + pafen_table.total_pafen) AS totalScore,
               joint_check_table.create_id AS createId, joint_check_table.create_name AS createName, joint_check_table.create_date AS createDate,
               joint_check_table.modify_id AS modifyId, joint_check_table.modify_name AS modifyName, joint_check_table.modify_date AS modifyDate,
               joint_check_table.del_flag AS delFlag, joint_check_table.version AS version
            FROM
        (
            SELECT <include refid="Company_Column_List"></include>
            FROM
            (
                SELECT <include refid="Project_Column_List"></include>
                FROM pm_police_company_joint_check
                WHERE del_flag = 1 AND check_record_type = #{checkRecordType}
                <if test="companyId != null and companyId != ''">
                    AND company_id = #{companyId}
                </if>
                <if test="query.year != null">
                    AND YEAR(check_date) = #{query.year}
                </if>
                <if test="query.startMonth != null">
                    AND #{query.startMonth} &lt;= MONTH(check_date)
                </if>
                <if test="query.endMonth != null">
                    AND #{query.endMonth} &gt;= MONTH(check_date)
                </if>
                GROUP BY proj_id
            ) AS proj_check_table GROUP BY company_id
        ) AS joint_check_table LEFT JOIN (

          SELECT pafen_id, company_id, check_date, SUM(pafen_score) AS total_pafen
          FROM pm_pafen
          WHERE del_flag = 1
            <if test="companyId != null and companyId != ''">
                AND company_id = #{companyId}
            </if>
            <if test="query.year != null">
                AND YEAR(check_date) = #{query.year}
            </if>
            <if test="query.startMonth != null">
                AND #{query.startMonth} &lt;= MONTH(check_date)
            </if>
            <if test="query.endMonth != null">
                AND #{query.endMonth} &gt;= MONTH(check_date)
            </if>
            GROUP BY company_id
        ) AS pafen_table ON joint_check_table.company_id = pafen_table.company_id
        ORDER BY totalScore DESC
    </select>
```

When I tried to use this method, an exception occured, the sql printed in the console like this:
The sql printed in the console like this:

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            check_id, check_date, check_record_type,
            company_id, company_name,
            AVG(rest_score) AS rest_score,
            proj_id, proj_name, problem_type, problem_id,
            problem_name, problem_description, 
            create_id, create_name, create_date,
            modify_id, modify_name, modify_date,
            del_flag, version
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    check_id, check_date, check_record_type,
                    company_id, company_name,
                    (100.00 - SUM(deduct_score)) AS rest_score,
                    proj_id, proj_name, problem_type,
                    problem_id, problem_name,
                    problem_description,
                    create_id, create_name, create_date, 
                    modify_id, modify_name, modify_date,
                    del_flag, version
                FROM
                    pm_police_company_joint_check
                WHERE
                    del_flag = 1
                AND check_record_type = ?
                AND company_id = ?
                AND YEAR (check_date) = ?
                AND ? <= MONTH (check_date)
                AND ? >= MONTH (check_date)
                GROUP BY
                    proj_id
            ) AS proj_check_table
        GROUP BY
            company_id
    ) AS joint_check_table
```

the ERROR's level log like this:

```java
org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not set parameters for mapping: ParameterMapping{property='companyId', mode=IN, javaType=class java.lang.Object, jdbcType=null, numericScale=null, resultMapId='null', jdbcTypeName='null', expression='null'}. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null for parameter #6 with JdbcType null . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different configuration property. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null for parameter #6 with JdbcType null . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different configuration property. Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (6 > number of parameters, which is 5).
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:92)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:440)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy129.selectList(Unknown Source)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectList(SqlSessionTemplate.java:223)
    at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.override.MybatisMapperMethod.executeForMany(MybatisMapperMethod.java:173)
    at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.override.MybatisMapperMethod.execute(MybatisMapperMethod.java:78)
    at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.override.MybatisMapperProxy$PlainMethodInvoker.invoke(MybatisMapperProxy.java:148)
    at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.override.MybatisMapperProxy.invoke(MybatisMapperProxy.java:89)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy226.selectJointCheckPageRedList(Unknown Source)
    at com.jiumai.base.pm.service.impl.PoliceCompanyJointCheckServiceImpl.findJointCheckRedPage(PoliceCompanyJointCheckServiceImpl.java:67)
    at com.jiumai.base.pm.service.impl.PoliceCompanyJointCheckServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$44e3d117.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:779)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692)
    at com.jiumai.base.pm.service.impl.PoliceCompanyJointCheckServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d8a064f8.findJointCheckRedPage(<generated>)
    at com.jiumai.base.pm.controller.PoliceCompanyJointCheckController.findJointCheckPage(PoliceCompanyJointCheckController.java:56)
    at com.jiumai.base.pm.controller.PoliceCompanyJointCheckController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$44809b5d.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:779)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692)
    at com.jiumai.base.pm.controller.PoliceCompanyJointCheckController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fa02311a.findJointCheckPage(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not set parameters for mapping: ParameterMapping{property='companyId', mode=IN, javaType=class java.lang.Object, jdbcType=null, numericScale=null, resultMapId='null', jdbcTypeName='null', expression='null'}. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null for parameter #6 with JdbcType null . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different configuration property. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null for parameter #6 with JdbcType null . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different configuration property. Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (6 > number of parameters, which is 5).
    at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.MybatisParameterHandler.setParameters(MybatisParameterHandler.java:215)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.parameterize(PreparedStatementHandler.java:94)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.parameterize(RoutingStatementHandler.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:63)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy306.parameterize(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:63)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy306.parameterize(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:63)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy306.parameterize(Unknown Source)
    at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.executor.MybatisSimpleExecutor.prepareStatement(MybatisSimpleExecutor.java:99)
    at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.executor.MybatisSimpleExecutor.doQuery(MybatisSimpleExecutor.java:68)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:325)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:156)
    at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.extension.plugins.inner.PaginationInnerInterceptor.willDoQuery(PaginationInnerInterceptor.java:134)
    at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.extension.plugins.MybatisPlusInterceptor.intercept(MybatisPlusInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:61)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy305.query(Unknown Source)
    at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.extension.plugins.MybatisPlusInterceptor.intercept(MybatisPlusInterceptor.java:65)
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:61)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy305.query(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:147)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:426)
    ... 88 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null for parameter #6 with JdbcType null . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different configuration property. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null for parameter #6 with JdbcType null . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different configuration property. Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (6 > number of parameters, which is 5).
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler.setParameter(BaseTypeHandler.java:75)
    at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.MybatisParameterHandler.setParameters(MybatisParameterHandler.java:213)
    ... 126 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null for parameter #6 with JdbcType null . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different configuration property. Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (6 > number of parameters, which is 5).
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler.setParameter(BaseTypeHandler.java:75)
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.UnknownTypeHandler.setNonNullParameter(UnknownTypeHandler.java:67)
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler.setParameter(BaseTypeHandler.java:73)
    ... 127 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (6 > number of parameters, which is 5).
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.checkBounds(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1375)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.getCoreParameterIndex(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1388)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.setString(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1755)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.setString(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.ibatis.logging.jdbc.PreparedStatementLogger.invoke(PreparedStatementLogger.java:67)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy307.setString(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.StringTypeHandler.setNonNullParameter(StringTypeHandler.java:31)
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.StringTypeHandler.setNonNullParameter(StringTypeHandler.java:26)
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler.setParameter(BaseTypeHandler.java:73)
    ... 129 common frames omitted
```

I've found the problem, if I remove the last four tag of "if", it works. With the message of exception, I think the parameter couldn't be used for more than once, are there any good solutions?
Thank you for your help

Comment: That's not the reason. As it's XML, you can't write `<` directly. Any of the following should resolve the problem. 1) write `<` as `&lt;`, 2) swap the condition i.e. `AND #{query.startMonth} >= MONTH(check_date)` (because `>` is allowed) or 3) use CDATA `<![CDATA[AND MONTH(check_date) <= #{query.startMonth}]]>`. You should enable DEBUG or TRACE level logging during development.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  For your first suggestion, I think I forgot to explain something, I use **&lt**; and **&gt**; instead of “<“ and “>“. To better show the code, I use “<“ and “>“ on my question, that's my fault. Then I have accepted your second suggestion about swaping the condition, but it still dosen't works, the same ERROR level's log still orrurs.

Comment: If you enabled DEBUG level logging, it will print the SQL that is causing the error along with the parameters. Please add the output to your question (you can 'edit' the question).

Comment: OK, I've done that.

Comment: Are you aware that the XML statement and the SQL in the log are completely different? If you didn't write the `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` query in the XML mapper, it probably is mybatis-plus that auto-generates the bad SQL. Try removing mybatis-plus and see if the problem reproduces.

Comment: I removed the parameter "PageModel" of the method in the interface about the mybatis-plus' auto paging plugin, then it runs successfully! It seems caused by some bug of mybatis-plus, maybe I need to implement the paging function by myself.